# How to install VSCode Extensions in Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, q#

I'm trying to run a Q# program that uses Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Convert, I added to my project file and included it in the code, but when I run 'dotnet run', I get '/workspace/QSharp/QSharpTest/QSharpTest.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Convert. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org'.

QSharpTest.csproj

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Canon"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Convert"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Operations.qs

```
namespace QSharpTest
{
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Primitive;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Convert;

    operation HelloQ () : Unit {
        let hello = GetHello();
        Message(hello);
        let multiple = multiply(2, 3);
        Message(ToStringI(multiple));
    }
    function GetHello () : (String) {
        return "Hello";
    }
    function multiply (a : Int, b : Int) : (Int) {
        return a*b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Convert` is a namespace, but it is not a separate NuGet package - it is included in `Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit` package. You should include a package reference to `Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit` in your project files. You can see examples in [existing Q# projects](https://github.com/Microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/Superposition/Superposition.csproj).

To do this automatically, you can create your project from scratch as a Q# project (as described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quickstart?view=qsharp-preview&tabs=tabid-vscode)) - this will create necessary package references automatically:

```
dotnet new console -lang Q# --output MyProject
```

Update: To address your updated question,

1. You don't need `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Convert"/>` in your csproj file - this is namespace, not package name.
2. You don't need `open Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit;` in your Q# file - this is package name, not namespace.
3. You probably need versions of NuGet packages in your csproj file:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Canon" Version="0.4.1901.3104" />`
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit" Version="0.4.1901.3104" />`

Comment: Regarding (1)… you meant you don't need  `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Convert"/>` in the csproj file...  `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Canon"/>` is still needed.

Comment: @Elcapi True. I'm spoiled by creating the csproj files automatically instead of editing them manually :-)

Answer (score 0):

Would you be willing to provide the contents of your `QSharpTest.csproj` file? It sounds like you've added `Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Convert` as a `<PackageReference />`, but as that error says, there's no such package— you probably want an `open` statement in your Q# source file itself:

```
namespace QSharp.Test {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Primitives;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Convert;

    // ...

}
```

As for the question in your title, the Visual Studio Code extension can be installed the same way on Ubuntu as on macOS or Windows 10. See the [Quantum Development Kit documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/install-guide/vs-code?view=qsharp-preview#installing-visual-studio-code-and-the-net-core-sdk-windows-10-macos-linux) for details, but one way to do so is to go to the [Quantum Development Kit extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quantum.quantum-devkit-vscode) on the [Visual Studio Code marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) and press "Install."